# Two beans (one being mocked) of same name and same class in AppContext

Tags: java, spring, mocking

I have two beans of the same name and same class. I want to mock (mocking is not done through `@Mock` annotation but done in the Spring file because of some reason) one of them and leave the other one as normal (used for integration tests).

One way, I could think of is to change `resource file` in `@ContextConfiguration's location attribute` and load separate configs for unit testing and integration testing.

Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

I understand that there are some issues like `Why not to use @Mock?`, `Why to have two beans of same class and same bean?` but I cannot change that because some part is already there and I don't want to change that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have separate configuration files when necessary for different purposes.  One scenario is one for testing and another for production.  I agree with your first thought.

Comment: But in my case, both the files are for testing, one for junits, one for integration tests. So, I would go with this approach assuming there is no other option.

Comment: @instanceOfObject a purist would say that anything that involves Spring is an integration test.